# Import XML with PHP, does not accept "-" in XML tag

Tags: php, html, xml, import, tags

This is somewhat what my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<citizen> 
  <military> 
    <rank-points>62750</rank-points> 
    <stars>1</stars> 
    <total-damage>18243</total-damage> 
    <rank>Commander</rank> 
    <fight-count>0</fight-count> 
  </military> 
</citizen>
```

Now, I want to import the stuff inside the tag "rank-points" with PHP using

```
$rank = $xml->{'military'}->rank-points;
```

But, because the XML tag has a "-" in it's name, it won't work. The result is always 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using this :

```
$rank = $xml->{'military'}->rank-points;
```

PHP will actually :

- search for `$xml->{'military'}->rank`
- and try to substract the value of the constant `points` to that value

  - if the contant doesn't exist, it'll use the string value `"points"`.

Trying to execute your code, you should actually get a notice, indicating what I said :

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant points - assumed 'points'
```

To solve that problem, try **adding `{''}` around the name of your tag** :

```
$rank = $xml->{'military'}->{'rank-points'};
```

This way, PHP will know that `rank-points` is one thing -- and not a substraction.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to encapsulate the `rank-points` in curly braces as well:

```
$rank = $xml->{'military'}->{'rank-points'};
```

PHP assumes that you're trying to substract the contant "point" from the variable $rank.

Answer (score 1):

The SimpleXML documentation has [**an example**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-4543) demonstrating exactly this problem; accessing elements within an XML document that contain characters not permitted under PHP's naming convention. The solution is to use an [**inline variable property**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), which basically means (in your case) wrapping the property name in `{'` and `'}`.

It is interesting that you chose to wrap `military` in the curly-brace syntax, albeit unnecessarily as it contains a perfectly valid plain property name (c.f. `rank-points`).

So your example could simply become:

```
$rank = $xml->military->{'rank-points'};
```